# How should one address concerns to a parliamentary representative?

Tags: europe, society, citizen-activism

I am concerned that politicians are not addressing some issues I see as having imminent impacts in the overall health of Europe.  I would like to communicate this effectively with a representative in parliament.

What is the most effective way to communicate with them, and how can I make sure that my concerns are properly communicated?

Comment: Thanks, @Chad for salvaging this question into something useful.

Comment: Well, *that's* one of the more radical edit histories I've ever seen on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Which country are we in here? In Britain the simplest way is to write a letter to your MP, let's say: James Fortescue MP, House of Commons, London SWIA 0AA, and express your concerns in writing. If you don't know who your MP is go to [this website](http://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/mps/) and enter your post code. You will receive your member's name and email address.

Comment: @WS2 This is to sent a letter to an EU representative. I am not sure who to contact based on the concern.

Comment: @Cpast - I agree and would never had made that edit except that we had a chat conversation and I told him what I would do he said go ahead, then approved of the edit after.